# Erro: DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled

Tags: java, hibernate, primefaces

Estou implementando uma lista de seleção (DataTable) porem só recebo este erro:
DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled.

Segue abaixo o código:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{vendaControle.listaDeVendas}" id="tabela"
                             rendered="#{vendaControle.tipoBusca != 'item'}"
                             rowStyleClass="#{item.cancelada eq true ? 'lineColor' : null}"
                             selection="#{vendaControle.venda}"
                             selectionMode="single"
                             rowKey="#{venda.id}"
                             emptyMessage="Não há registros!" paginator="false"
                             scrollable="true" scrollHeight="410" var="venda" style="text-align: left">

                    <p:column headerText="Código" filterBy="#{venda.id}" width="80" filterStyle="max-width: 70px;">
                        #{venda.id} 
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Empresa" rendered="#{fazendaControle.listaFazendas.size() gt 1}" width="150" filterBy="#{venda.empresa.nome}" filterStyle="max-width: 70px;">
                        #{venda.empresa.nome}
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Cliente" filterBy="#{venda.pessoa.nome}" width="350" filterStyle="width: 200px;">
                        #{venda.pessoa.nome}
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Horário" width="50">
                        <h:outputText value="#{venda.dtVendaTela}">
                            <f:convertDateTime pattern="HH:mm"/>
                        </h:outputText>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Tipo" width="200">

                        <h:outputText value="#{venda.tipoDeVenda}"/>

                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Fiscal" width="80">
                        <h:outputText value="#{venda.codNfe}" rendered="#{venda.fiscal eq true and venda.codNfe != null}"/>
                        <h:outputText value="#{venda.codNfce}" rendered="#{venda.fiscal eq true and venda.codNfce != null}"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Vendedor" filterBy="#{venda.nomeFun}" width="250" filterStyle="width: 130px;">
                        <h:outputText value="#{venda.nomeFun}"/>
                    </p:column>


                    <p:column headerText="Total (R$)" style="text-align: right" width="100">
                        <h:outputText value="#{venda.totalDesc}">
                            <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="2"
                                             maxFractionDigits="2"
                                             />
                        </h:outputText>
                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>
                <p:contextMenu for="tabela">
                    <p:menuitem value="Gerar Cupom" action="#{relatorioControle.gerarReciboVendaCupom(vendaControle.venda.id)}" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-print"/>

                    <p:menuitem value="Gerar Comprovante" ajax="false" action="#{relatorioControle.gerarReciboVenda(vendaControle.venda.id)}"
                                icon="ui-icon-print"/>

                    <p:menuitem value="Gerar Receita" ajax="false" rendered="#{loginControler.moduloOtica eq true}" action="#{relatorioControle.gerarReciboVendaReceita(vendaControle.venda.id)}"
                                icon="ui-icon-print"/>

                    <p:menuitem value="Compartilhar" onclick="PF('dlgEmail').show()"
                                icon="ui-icon-mail-closed"/>

                    <p:menuitem value="Editar" action="#{vendaControle.editar(vendaControle.venda)}" ajax="false"
                                icon="ui-icon-pencil"/>

                    <p:menuitem value="Excluir" action="#{vendaControle.validaEstornoVenda(vendaControle.venda)}"
                                onclick="if (!confirm('Deseja realmente excluir essa venda?'))
                                            return false"
                                ajax="false"
                                icon="ui-icon-trash"/>

                </p:contextMenu>
```

Bean

```
  public void carregaListaDeVendas() {

    if (tipoBusca == null) {
        tipoBusca = "data";
    }

    if (tipoBusca.equals("nome")) {
        if (pessoa.getId() == 0) {
            listaDeVendas = null;

        } else {
            listaDeVendas = vendaFacade.validaVendaDiasPessoa(pessoa);

        }

    } else if (tipoBusca.equals("data")) {
        pessoa = pessoaFacade.listaUm().get(0);

        if (somenteConsumidor == Boolean.TRUE) {
            listaDeVendas = vendaFacade.validaVendaDiasConsumidor(dataFiltro, dataFiltro2, pessoa);

        } else {
            listaDeVendas = vendaFacade.validaVendaDias(dataFiltro, dataFiltro2);

        }

    } else if (tipoBusca.equals("cod")) {
        listaDeVendas = vendaFacade.validaVendaCod(id);

    } else if (tipoBusca.equals("item")) {
        listaDeItensVendas = itemVendaFacade.listaProdutoPorVenda(produto, dataFiltro, dataFiltro2);
    }
}
```

Erro

```
Advertência:   StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
```

javax.faces.FacesException: DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled.
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getRowKeyFromModel(DataTable.java:1259)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRow(DataTableRenderer.java:961)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRows(DataTableRenderer.java:907)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:854)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeScrollBody(DataTableRenderer.java:408)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeScrollableTable(DataTableRenderer.java:355)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:249)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:87)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:89)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:206)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:123)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:58)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Coloca a sua implementação e coloca a stack do erro completa por favor.

Comment: Pronto Editei a Pergunta

Comment: Da uma olhadinha nesta resposta, ve se atende você...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526857/facesexception-datamodel-must-implement-org-primefaces-model-selectabledatamode